# reference html value in rails 4 form

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a select box within a form. It's html is:

```
<td id = xxx>
    <select id =yyy, name = aaa[bbb]>
        <option value=1>"Yes"</option>
        <option value=2>"No"</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

How can I reference the option selected by the user in the rails form? i.e. I want to be able to do something like:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :name, :value => aaa[bbb].value %>
```

(Note: there is no rails variable because I am dynamically generating the select box using javascript)

Comment: `I am dynamically generating the select box using javascript` Fill hidden field value using JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: How do I do that? Can i so something like: f.hidden_field :name, :value => $('select#select_id :selected') ?

Comment: @user3711600 Satpal is pretty much saying that you can't use Ruby/Rails syntax to do what you want to do. Use JavaScript (i.e., `$('#yyy').change(function() { /* Handle it here */ });`).

Comment: got it. is it possible to use javascript within a rails view, or do i have to create a new .js file, with corresponding controller action? (thanks! rails newbie here)

Comment: Just add a js file in the assets folder with the name of your view and do all your manipulation from there. In order to do things with the information you gather from the select input you can just use an AJAX call and go from there passing along any other info you might need as data parameters. Be sure to add that call to your routes file.